# How can I determine why IIS is recycling my app in shared hosting?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've deployed an ASP.NET MVC app (on runtime 4.5.2), which works in development, and also on Azure.

But when deployed to my actual production environment, which is shared hosting on IIS 8.5, I get frequent app recycles, *usually every few minutes or after only two or three requests*! Sometimes the app bombs so badly, I need to ask them to restart it manually because it doesn't restart automatically.

The only thing I've done which is maybe non-standard, is I've disabled session state in `web.config`, because I don't use session.

In `Application_Error` I log errors. In `Application_End` I log `HostingEnvironment.ShutdownReason`, which is always equal to `HostingEnvironment`, which isn't helpful, because all that means is `"The hosting environment shut down the application domain."`

They refuse to let me see their server logs.

My app is (I think) bug-free, and as I stated above, it works perfectly on Azure. So there is a problem somewhere between how IIS is configured, and my app behaves.

*What can I do to drill down into this problem?*

Comment: I haven't tried "Health Monitoring" yet, would that help? From what little I understand about it, it won't give me extra insight into the problem, given that this is shared hosting.

Comment: IIS is always recycling application pools (ie *restarts*), especially in shared hosting. It's a reliability feature, not a problem to disable. If you have a lot of recycles it's because your application consistently fails, either by having too high CPU for too long, or consuming too much memory, or working so slow that its request queue exceeds the limit. Stress-test your application to  see how it behaves under load. Or it may be that the hoster put so many sites on the same machine that all of them are failing under load

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes but like I stated it recycles every few minutes. Sometimes after *only two or three requests*. That means there's a serious problem somewhere.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The idea that maybe the server is too busy is possible, but I doubt it, as I'm using a reputable hosting company. I could tell for sure if I could see the logs, or the IIS config file, but they refuse.

Comment: Use a monitoring service,  eg Azure's Application Insights which is currently free. You *can* register your code to receive a notification whenever the application pool is about to recycle, as [shown  here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) but you don't get the reason. You could check counters etc and log them somewhere but App Insights is a faster solution.

Comment: You have to stress test your application though. In a similar situation, an undetected infinite recursion resulted in 100% CPU and recycling only when a very specific request was made.

Comment: Furthermore, the fact you need to ask them to restart means that IIS has recycled your site *repeatedly* before deciding to stop recycling it. The hoster may have set the limits too low or put too many machines on the same server, resulting in far more frequent recycles than eg in Azure

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Good ideas, thanks. But stress testing isn't necessary, because it's literally restarting after a few requests. It doesn't stay up for more than a few minutes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes that makes sense. It's a pity there's no tool to give me the restart reason so I can cross-reference the IIS config.

Comment: That's why I mentioned Application Insights. It's exactly such a tool/service. The reason *is* written in the server's Event Log but you can't do anything if they won't even tell you what it was. App Insights also solves the problem of *where* to store your log - obviously you can't write on the server's disk

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am going to try it as you recommend. But, I want to find the error on the shared hosting provider, not on Azure, because when I test on Azure everything works. So I'm unsure how much insight it will give me into the problem in the production environment.

Comment: You don't need to run your site on Azure. The data is collected on your hosted site and sent to Azure for storage and processing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've implemented Application Insights. But it doesn't provide extra info that I couldn't get elsewhere, or maybe I'm not looking in the right place? Basically, it can't see into IIS, which is hidden from me in shared hosting...